# Why each time I search info about REST I see almost always, a relation with API?

Tags: php, rest

I've never used or try any *ReST* application, but it seems that it uses the proper *HTTP* requests for the proper things, instead of the `POST` and `GET` usage.

So, if I wish to create a web application, and I wish to make some CRUD operations, I assume for almost operation, I will have:

```
 POST for create. 

 GET for read. 

 PUT for update. 

 DELETE for delete.
```

Why do we see so many clear relations between this architecture (**ReST**) and *API development*, and we seem not to see it on common *MVC applications* developed using a given PHP Framework?

Can anyone clarify a little but more about the whys on those associations?

Comment: rest is a buzzword like anything else. you don't have to use its precepts to get the job done.

Comment: Most 'common' applications are only data retrieval, so `GET`'s for the most part. In essance, _any_ website is kind-of-a-rest-application. Granted, usually with some blatant disregard for some standards, but the core principles are there nonetheless. With a clear absence of `PUT` & `DELETE` because browsers tend to not support a  `<form method="PUT">` or `<form method="DELETE">` natively. Browser builders could support that if they wanted to.

Comment: But according to the HTTP specifications it would be important to make the path towards that no? But, why do we see so many associations of `REST and APIs`, and not `REST and MVC Framework Applications`? Does a API development has special things...?

Comment: You mean having a clear site-navigation, and logical urls for a website? Good sites have those. I know a few of them that would also react quite well & different if I send another `Accept-Encoding` then `HTML`, using the same urls for HTML representation & others without much chrome around it (json, xml, etc.). If you want to build a great website, my advise would be to do that.

Comment: @Wrikken: so the reason we don't see many ReST applications around may be due to the fact that browsers don't actually support some ReST specifications, at least, not at the same extension that they do with POST and GET?

Comment: To summarize it better then I could: [_"The World Wide Web represents the largest implementation of a system conforming to the REST architectural style."_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST)

Comment: The web is REST, only some people write crappy REST interfaces (in other words: crappy websites). REST is just what to call it more abstract, as it is not limited to the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a *"MVC applications"*, I'm blatently assuming you mean a website, although an *"MVC applications"* can of course be something else entirely. A website is REST, but it may provide a crappy interface on certain sites. With a clear absence of PUT & DELETE because browsers tend to not support a `<form method="PUT">` or `<form method="DELETE">` natively. Browser builders could support that if they wanted to.

To quote Wikipedia:

> The World Wide Web represents the largest implementation of a system conforming to the REST architectural style.

To loop through [the constraints as given on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST#Constraints)

- Client–server: webserver and browser, we've got those.
- Stateless: yes, a request to a URL usually does not care about client state (we've got keep-alive to keep things fast, but everything is in essence a new request). Some things to point out due to server session: *"session state is held in the client"* (i.e. your authentication information or token, and anything else you like to remember about the site you visit) & *"Important to note is that the session state can be transferred by the server to another service such as a database to maintain a persistent state for a period of time and allow authentication."* => session-cookies with more data on the server are alright for REST
- Cacheable: yes, most identities (webpages) can be cached, or configured not to cache.
- Layered system: lots of proxies & load balancers, but everything keeps working on the web.
- Code on demand: it there's one thing that webpages often serve...
- Uniform Interface[edit]

  - Individual resources are identified in requests: that would be what URLs are.
  - Manipulation of resources: forms (if you have the permission for them)
  - Self-descriptive messages: mime-types a plenty, usually with `Content-type: text/html` though. Headers tell whether it can be cached.
  - Hypermedia as the engine of application state (A.K.A. HATEOAS): if the web isn't a collection of hyperlinks I don't know what it is.

So, the web is REST, so why would we have to state that about websites explicitly? There are of course things to consider to make it work userfriendly: an URL should point to a resource, so gettting only representation without modification should be `GET` requests. So, those search forms that work with `POST`'s rather then `GET`'s, so there is no way to share a search results? Those are design flaws made by the websites creator. Those `GET` urls that alter content on the server? Anyone having worked a few months in the field *knows* one shouldn't use `GET`'s for those. Showing other *main content* (different navbars etc. are OK) on a *public* page with the same URL due to some session state is a design flaw (and it will hurt your sites use, due to users and crawlers not being able to *share* that url). Etc. etc.

REST is a nice way to talk about websites, if only because it explicitly states the ground rules that were always there for the web more abstract & clear, which helps your design. It is true a significant amount of people do not realize this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the consideration towards the question. It helped on clarifying things a bit. :)

Answer (score 1):

MVC applications are targeted at a human user. APIs are targeted at a machine user.

Whatever makes sense in terms of guiding the human to get the task done probably is bloated in a machine interface (or maybe not, because the usual human user of a machine interface is a developer).